# Finding number of positive integers based on condition given

Tags: contest-math, real-numbers

This problem is from prmo 2021

> find sum of all positive integers n for which $|2^n+5^n-65|$ is a perfect square

My method

$2^n+5^n-65=\pm m^2$

### case 1

$2^n+5^n=65-m^2$

This is satisfied by n=2 only

### case 2

$2^n+5^n=65+m^2$

This condition gave me value for many n on counting right from n=1 to large number which increases the chance of missing a number. Is there a better way to calculate without actually counting all numbers

Comment: I have a feeling that it would be a good idea to consider the expression in mod something. Perhaps mod 4 ?

Comment: modulo algebra is not introduced at their level @MattiP.

Comment: @CalvinLin question not yet answered even there